# Redis Memorystore from GCP send pubsub notification on notify-keyspace-events

Tags: redis, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-memorystore

Assuming I have a Redis instance running on Google Memory store if there any way to send a Google PubSub notification on `notify-keyspace-events` events?

My ultimate goal is to trigger a cloud function subscribed to a topic that I can listen to on the event.

So far I've only been able to accomplish this using a dedicate node instance listing for the event.

Anyway to go around this? The documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/reference/redis-configs) doesn't mention anything related.

Comment: Did you find any workaround for this?

Comment: @EmAe not supported :(